# Replacing the script tag type and applying it

Tags: javascript, performance

Is there any way to replace the `script type` with javascript only and execute it

this is an example script

`<script id="myscript" src='myscript.js' type='text/template'></script>`

i want to replace `type` with `text/javascript` i tried this code to replace it and it does replace the type but the script is not applied to the site.

`<script>document.querySelector("#myscript").setAttribute("type","text/javascript");<script>`

Comment: Unusual request. What is the use case for this?

Answer (score 0):

Make a new script instead, one with the proper type.

```
const existing = document.querySelector("#myscript");
const newScript = existing.cloneNode();
newScript.type = 'text/javascript';
existing.replaceWith(newScript);
```

Or just take the `src` of the existing one.

```
const existingSrc = document.querySelector("#myscript").src;
document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('script')).src = existingSrc;
```

Comment: replacewith is not working in firefox

Comment: sorry, i mean the script is not execute in firefox